# Bluemix and Liberty Profile 8.5.5.6

Tags: ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty

Liberty Profile 8.5.5.6, which is a full Java EE 7 implementation, was released yesterday.

When will 8.5.5.6 be available on BlueMix?

Comment: Why don´t you ask IBM? Seems like those products are both from them, so they might know.

Comment: @flomei, Asking Bluemix questions here is acceptable -- and encouraged!

Comment: Obviously yes, I just thought IBM might be more "spot on" concerning release dates.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Liberty 8.5.5.6 is already supported by the buildpack v1.19, [released a few days ago](https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2015/06/16/liberty-buildpack-app-management-support/?preview=true). If the default buildpack in Bluemix does not yet pick it up, you can explicitly point to [this buildpack](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/ibm-websphere-liberty-buildpack) in github: in the [liberty container notes](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/ibm-websphere-liberty-buildpack/blob/master/docs/container-liberty.md) (click on "details for candidate versions"), as of today you will [already find 8.5.5.6](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/ibm-websphere-liberty-buildpack/blob/master/docs/util-repositories.md) listed (among four other earlier versions).

Comment: Hello, I am following the guides here but even after including both licenses in the manifest I get this error: -----> Downloading IBM 1.8.0_sr1fp01 JRE from https://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/websphere/wasdev/downloads/jre/1.8.0/linux/ibm-java-jre-8.0-1.1-x86_64-archive.bin ... (3m 9s)
         Expanding JRE to .java ... 
Error: You need to accept the license to install this product. Could someone post here the URLs for Java 8 and Liberty 8.5.5.6 licenses? The ones in those links seem outdated (for example, Java 7... I got the license D/N for Java 8 but is not recognised).

Answer (score 0):

The exact date is not announced. Stay tuned to the [bluemix blog](https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/blog/) for the release information. The current Liberty driver is based on the April beta, which likely has the features you are looking for! EE 7!

See this [blog post](https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2015/05/05/liberty-buildpack-updates-java-8-java-ee-7-updates/) for more details.